# Replacing all chars in string in one run

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am trying to replace chars from a string by splitting it into a list and iterating over it.

I have created a dictionary for all the key which needs to be replaced with values.

```
dicta = {
    "eq" : "=",
    "gt" : ">",
    "lt" : "<"
}

s = "name eq 'alex' and age gt 36"
[s.replace(char, dicta.get(char)) for char in s.split(" ") if char in dicta ]
```

The above solution gives me the output :

```
["name = 'alex' and age gt 36", "name eq 'alex' and age > 36"]
```

It's because I am creating the whole string after one char change.

**Expected Output:** `["name = 'alex' and age > 36"]`

How can I do it in just one run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex solution: (This will also replace keys found in other words like `eq` in `equality` will be replaced: `=uality`)

```
import re

dicta = {
    "eq" : "=",
    "gt" : ">",
    "lt" : "<"
}

s = "name eq 'alex' and age gt 36 equality"

# pattern that matches every key in dicta with white space around it
pattern = '|'.join(dicta.keys())

ans = re.sub(pattern, lambda x : dicta.get(x.group(0)), s)

print(ans)
```

Edit:
Here is a split and join approach: (This will replace multiple spaces between words with a single space tho)

```
dicta = {
    "eq" : "=",
    "gt" : ">",
    "lt" : "<"
}

s = "name eq 'alex' and age gt 36 equality"   
ans = ' '.join([dicta.get(word, word)for word in s.split()])

print(ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

dict = {
    "eq" : "=",
    "gt" : ">",
    "lt" : "<"
}

s = "name eq 'alex' and age gt 36"


reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(y, dict[y]), dict, s)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example replaces all instances of the operator keywords. It also ensures that embedded words such as equity are ignored.

```
dicta = {
    "eq" : "=",
    "gt" : ">",
    "lt" : "<"
}

s = "name eq 'alex' and age gt 36"

words = s.split(" ")
result = []
for w in words:
    result.append(dicta.get(w,w))

print(" ".join(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

using regex and `\b` to match word boundary, this will avoid word equality being replace.

regex match word, if key not match in dicta, same word will be return.

```
dicta = {
    "eq" : "=",
    "gt" : ">",
    "lt" : "<"
}

s = "name eq 'alex' and age gt 36"

import re


ans = re.sub(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(dicta.keys())), lambda x : dicta.get(x.group(0), x.group(0)), s)
### can try regex below also
# ans = re.sub(r'\b(\w+)\b', lambda x : dicta.get(x.group(0), x.group(0)), s)

# "name = 'alex' and age > 36"
```

Comment: The length of words in dictionary might not be 2 always.

Comment: For that case u may replace the pattern with `'|'.join(dicta.keys()` as commented

Comment: Thanks for your effort, this also replaces words like `equity` to `=uity`. I think looping over is the best way.

Comment: i guess you are miss out the `\b` regex, i have edited the answer for using dicta.keys()

Answer (score 0):

I think, the issue with your code is below :

```
>>> s="name eq"
>>> s.replace('eq','=')
'name ='
>>> s.replace('name','Name')
'Name eq'
>>>
```

You have to save the first replacement and use it for second replacement.

**Code :**

```
dicta = {
    "eq" : "=",
    "gt" : ">",
    "lt" : "<"
}

s = "name eq 'alex' and age gt 36"

d= s.split(" ")
for char in s.split(" "):
    if char in dicta.keys():
        s = s.replace(str(char), str(dicta.get(char)))
print s
```

**Output:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\python.exe" C:/Users/punddin/PycharmProjects/demo/demo.py
name = 'alex' and age > 36
```